# How to correctly create a ofstream of a struct vector? (abort() is called)

Tags: c++

I'm currently building a game and in this part my goal is to update a previously created file of High Scores ("rank.txt")

To do so, I've created a couple of functions so they can read what's in the txt file and so it can update it. Though the reading is ok, while adding the update function it gives me an error and tells me abort() has been called.

```
void highScoresUpdate(vector<PlayerInfo> player)
{
// This function is responsible for updating the High Scores Table present in the RANK.TXT file

vector<HighScoresStruct> highScores_temp;
HighScoresStruct temp;
ofstream out_file_3("rank.txt");


highScores_temp = readHighScores("rank.txt");

for (int k = 0; k < player.size(); k++)
{
player[k].name = temp.name;
player[k].score = temp.score;
player[k].time = temp.time;

highScores_temp.push_back(temp);
}

sort(highScores_temp.begin(), highScores_temp.end(), compareByScore);

for (int i = 0; i < highScores_temp.size(); i++)
{
    out_file_3 << highScores_temp[i].name << endl << highScores_temp[i].score << endl << highScores_temp[i].time << endl;
}

out_file_3.close();


}
```

For background information, so i don't spam this thread with code all you need to know is that readHighScores is the function responsible for extracting information from the txt file and placing it on a vector .
The structs and comparebyScore funtion are listed below.

```
bool compareByScore(const HighScoresStruct &a, const HighScoresStruct &b)
{
    if (a.score < b.score)
        return true;
    else if (a.score == b.score)
    {
        if (a.time > b.time)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

struct PlayerInfo
{
    string name;
    unsigned int score;
    vector<char> hand;
    bool inGame;
    unsigned int time;
};

struct HighScoresStruct
{
    string name;
    unsigned int score;
    unsigned int time;
};
```

So... Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you used the debugger and single stepped through your code, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of those variables?  Please edit your post with the information.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but you are never assigning to any `temp` data members so everything you add to `highScores_temp` has no name and the same uninitialized score and time.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Visual Studio, but in using the debugger it appeared the following error:
- Unhandled exception at 0x756F3E28 in Word_Game.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x00C6F5F4.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure that is causing the issue, since I've used the same "strategy" in the readHighScores function and it's working fine

Comment: @MasterExcrement I assume you meant to do `temp.name = player[k].name;` instead of the other way around?

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, that's a bit embarassing :p However the error still stands

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the crash? The debugger should show you exactly where it happens

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry, but I think I'm completely out of my league here. I've had the first subject on programming in C++ this semester and we've not used debuggers in any class. I'm sorry if I wasted a lot of your time :\